# Is this plant in my urban garden poison ivy?

Tags: species-identification, botany, poison

Is this plant in my urban garden poison ivy?

- Toronto, Ontario area.
- July 19, 2023
- Full shade
- Three leaves; toothed but not serrated.

[image]

---

**Possible Answer:** (I can’t post an answer due to the question being closed)

I suspect it is Boston Ivy (*Parthenocissus tricuspidata*).

> [Eastern Poison Ivy vs Boston Ivy](https://bplant.org/compare/1409-2420)
>
> Boston Ivy: A deciduous woody vine native to east Asia, introduced in North America. Established in numerous scattered locations, mostly around urban areas. It is a close relative of the native Virginia creeper.
>
> Middle leaflet has no stem or a short stem not much longer than that of side leaflets.
>
> [image]

Related: [Vine has simple and compound leaves](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/112699/vine-appears-to-have-both-simple-and-compound-leaves?noredirect=1#comment207266_112699)

Comment: Virginia creeper has leaves in 5s, not leaves in 3s. Definitely not virginia creeper.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly *Toxicodendron* (poison ivy) genus; I think *Toxicodendron rydbergii* ([western poison ivy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toxicodendron_rydbergii)). Leaves are in threes, with the central one longer than the others. Leaves are variable in toothing and serrations on the same plant. This one will be a shrub rather than a climbing vine.

Incidentally, the other, dark-green leaved, plant in there is [common ivy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedera_helix) (*Hedera helix*).